# Is it possible to have two while loops queried together? Is there a simple syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to have this `

```
while ($product_result_row = $product_result->fetch_assoc())
```

and this

```
while ($customer_result_row = $customer_result->fetch_assoc())
```

together in one while loop rather then two?

btw customer_result = `$Connection(THE DB)->query($sql_customer_query(MYSQL QUERY);`

Comment: Depends on how the queries relate. Either use nested loops, or combine the fetching per `and` or `or`. Better yet JOIN the SQL queries if the data sets are connected.

Comment: You can also use `UNION` in two queries !!

Comment: using the product query i make a table with all the details of products, with a button in teh end column that links to another page and that page used $_GET to find which row (information) from the previous page. I want to used the customer query to take the customer name and recive it in the next page along with the product info.